# How to parse POST AJAX data using golang?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm sending data to a golang app using ajax like this:

```
 httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 if (!httpRequest) {
     document.getElementById("errorArea").innerText = "Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance'";
  }

url =  "http://127.0.0.1:8080/putContent?url="+window.location.pathname;

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = sendContents;
httpRequest.open('POST', url);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var fd = new FormData();
fd.set ("data",document.getElementById("ta").value);
httpRequest.send(fd);
```

And the backend goes something like this:

```
r.ParseForm()
fmt.Print("postform=")
fmt.Println(r.PostForm)
```

The result (with sdfsdf typed into textarea ta):

```
 postform=map[------WebKitFormBoundarytZ4Y8wFVKpWBWBnu
 Content-Disposition: form-data:[]  name:["data"

 sdfsdf
 ------WebKitFormBoundarytZ4Y8wFVKpWBWBnu--
 ]] 
 ------------
```

**EDIT**

Found  the problem.The issue is that FormData sends data as `curl -H 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data $'------WebKitFormBoundaryiVVK2EjSLDbqaccx\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="data"\r\n\r\nsdfsdf\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryiVVK2EjSLDbqaccx--\r\n' --compressed`

instead of `curl --data "data=sdfsdf"

Now, how the real question is how to get FormData to send normal data?

Answer (score 0):

You can access HTTP POST data with `FormValue` method form `http.Request` object. I assume your `r` is `*http.Request` object. then you should be able to access your `data` with `r.FormValue("data")`. Example:

```
var myVariable string
myVariable = r.FormValue("data")
```

documentation:
[Go-Lang net/http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue)

Comment: Doesn't work. Still breaks the "post" value in half.

Answer (score 0):

Try *not* setting the request content-type in JS. Apparently the browser does this automatically when sending FormData() objects.

```
// Delete this line
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

I can't find a particular official statement on this, but if you look across all the various FormData() demos, none of them set the request content-type. In any case, it uses "multipart/form-data".

On my Go server, the typical Go r.ParseForm() and decoder seems to work just fine in initial tests.